# Issue in passing CHEF:ChefHost parameter for Chef Workflow in vRealize Orchestrator API

Tags: chef-infra, vmware

I have an environment with vRealize Orchestrator with CHEF plugin installed. I want to call the API for initiating a CHEF workflow in vRealize Orchestrator.

Say I want to call the CHEF workflow `Add New Role`. The input parameters for this workflow are

```
<input-parameters>
  <parameter description="Chef Server" type="CHEF:ChefHost" name="host"/>
  <parameter description="Name of new role" type="string" name="role"/>
  <parameter description="(Optional) Description of new role" type="string" name="description"/>
</input-parameters>
```

The format for sending parameters of the form `type="string"` is

1. In JSON

   ```
   {
   "value":{"string":{"value": "role name"}},
   "type": "string",
   "name": "role"
   }
   ```
2. In XML

   ```
   <execution-context  xmlns="http://www.vmware.com/vco">
      <parameters>
         <parameter name="role" type="string">
            <string>Role Name</string>
          </parameter>
       </parameters>
   </execution-context>
   ```

The problem I'm facing is with the parameter `type="CHEF:ChefHost"`. I can't get the correct syntax for `type="CHEF:ChefHost"`. I'm always getting a `400` error with description `The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.`

Is there any document which shows how to create a `CHEF:ChefHost` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had asked the same question in vmware community and I got an [answer](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2598380#2598380) from there.

> Chef hosts, as any other plug-in objects, are passed as sdk-object objects that are uniquely identified by their type and id attributes

```
<execution-context xmlns="http://www.vmware.com/vco">  
<parameters>  
    <parameter name="host" type="CHEF:ChefHost">  
        <sdk-object type="Chef:Host" id=<Enter host id>/>  
    </parameter>  
</parameters>
```